# Tkinter was working on Visual Studio Code but now it won't run

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I followed a tkinter tutorial a few days ago and tkinter worked fine. I deleted the project from my visual code file and when I tried to use tkinter again. The window for it will not appear. I checked to see if tkinter was installed and it still is.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
broken = tkinter.Label(root, text="Work Goddamnit!")

broken.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error that you get in visual studio?

Comment: The code is working as expected. Make sure you have checked the entire screen because the window is very small.